# Apple Watch not receiving notifications from Firestore Cloud Messaging Notification

Tags: ios, google-cloud-platform, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-watch

I use firestore cloud messaging (from a cloud function) to trigger notifications to apple devices:

```
const payload = {
    notification: {
      title, 
      body,
      sound: "default",
    },
    data: payloadBody
  };
```

This works as expected and doesn't have any issues, I can pull the payload from the ios code, the notification displays etc. However, apple watches don't receive the notification. I've checked all settings, tried multiple devices, etc.

Do we have to store fcm tokens for watches separatley? Or what needs to be done to achieve notifications on watches? Or should this work as default behaviour and a bug ticket be raised?